# How can I run more than one function in main() using Xcode?

Tags: xcode

I have three .c files and when I have the main() in the main.c file run the other functions in the other files, it only runs the first one it comes across, howcome? I have tried flipping the first running practice.c and practice2.c and it runs only the first one it comes across.

main.c

```
//
//  main.c
//  MyApp
//
//  Created by Julian on 8/28/20.
//  Copyright © 2020 CSCI. All rights reserved.
//

#include <stdio.h>             /* printf definitions */


int main(void)
{
    //Problem inputs stored in memory locations for use later

    //None for this problem, as we are just printing "pretty lines"

    printf("Hello World\n");
    practice2();
    practice();
    
    getchar();

    return (0);
}
```

practice.c

```
//
//  practice.c
//  MyApp
//
//  Created by Julian on 8/28/20.
//  Copyright © 2020 CSCI. All rights reserved.
//

#include "practice.h"

/* Program to print a few lines on the screen */


#include <stdio.h>             /* printf definitions */


int practice(void)
{
    //Problem inputs stored in memory locations for use later

    //None for this problem, as we are just printing "pretty lines"

    printf("Hello World\n");
    printf("What would you like to print on the screen?");
    printf("notice when you run this does not start on a new line....\n\n");
    printf("this one does, what is the difference??\n");

    getchar();

    return (0);
}
```

practice2.c

```
//
//  practice2.c
//  MyApp
//
//  Created by Julian on 8/29/20.
//  Copyright © 2020 CSCI. All rights reserved.
//

#include "practice2.h"

#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE
#include <stdio.h>             /* printf, scanf definitions */
#define KMS_PER_MILE 1.609     /* conversion constant       */

int practice2(void)
{
    double miles, /* input - distance in miles.      */
        kms;   /* output - distance in kilometers */

 /* Get the distance in miles. */
    printf("Enter the distance in miles > ");
    scanf("%lf", &miles);

    /* Convert the distance to kilometers. */
    kms = KMS_PER_MILE * miles;

    /* Display the distance in kilometers. */
    printf("That equals %f kilometers.\n", kms);

    getchar();
    getchar();

    return (0);
}
```

Comment: I don't see a problem.  I'm running in Xcode and press return to satisfy the getchar calls.  My observed output: "Hello World
Enter the distance in miles > 2
That equals 3.218000 kilometers.

Hello World
What would you like to print on the screen?notice when you run this does not start on a new line....

this one does, what is the difference??
"

Comment: Why have you not included the headers in main.c ?

Comment: How to include the headers? and no its not working, it only prints the first function it comes across.

Comment: Phillip Mills did you include the headers? Both functions are not appearing, it only does the first one it comes across.

Comment: Yes, I included headers but that was for compile warnings, not a run-time problem.  I showed you the output I see...I don't have an explanation for why you see something different.